# Is there a way to get LibVlc loaded buffer percentage?

Tags: android, vlc, libvlc

I'm currently making a city webcam app which uses libVlc to display the rtsp stream coming from the city webcams. My question is, it is possible to get the actual loaded state of the stream? I would like to show to the user. I can see in Android Studio runLog that there is some kind of buffering but cannot find in the code.

```
D/VLC: core input: Buffering 56%
D/VLC: core input: Buffering 58%
D/VLC: core input: Buffering 61%
D/VLC: core input: Buffering 64%
D/VLC: core input: Buffering 66%
D/VLC: core input: Buffering 69%
D/VLC: core input: Buffering 72%
D/VLC: core input: Buffering 72%
D/VLC: core input: Buffering 77%
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like requesting either player or media state will not return Buffering as the current state but will return Paused or Playing instead. So the only way to know it's in the buffering state is if the buffer event (such as shown in the answers below) is called with a value less than 100%

Answer (score 5):

This is for `libvlc:2.1.1`. you can get the buffer percentage using something like this ->

- Implement `MediaPlayer.EventListener` on your video player activity.
- Attach your media player event listener to current activity: `mMediaPlayer.setEventListener(this);`
- Override `onEvent` method in your activity
- In that method you can get the buffer float using `event.getBuffering()`:

  ```
  @Override
  public void onEvent(MediaPlayer.Event event) {
      switch(event.type) {
          case MediaPlayer.Event.Buffering:
              Log.d("BUFFERING", ""+event.getBuffering());
              break;
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: event.getBuffering() isn't a method available , m getting error, is there any other way?

Comment: Its available in the current master of [libvlc](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-android/blob/ea9ac596f85472ea8cac000f28e76d26f0c9b617/libvlc/src/org/videolan/libvlc/MediaPlayer.java#L113). Which version of libvlc are you using @AnjaniMittal ?

Comment: I am using 3.0.0. @Chirag

Answer (score 1):

You should attach to `libvlc_MediaPlayerBuffering` event.

Answer (score 1):

I add this version of vlc android sdk

compile 'de.mrmaffen:vlc-android-sdk:2.0.6'

```
 private static class MyPlayerListener implements MediaPlayer.EventListener {

    private WeakReference<VlcPlayerActivity> mOwner;

    public MyPlayerListener(VlcPlayerActivity owner) {
        mOwner = new WeakReference<VlcPlayerActivity>(owner);
    }

    @Override
    public void onEvent(MediaPlayer.Event event) {
        VlcPlayerActivity player = mOwner.get();

        switch (event.type) {
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Buffering:
                Log.d(TAG, ""+event.getBuffering());
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.Event.EndReached:
                Log.d(TAG, "MediaPlayerEndReached");
                player.releasePlayer();
                break;
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Playing:
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Paused:
            case MediaPlayer.Event.Stopped:
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: any solution for libvlc 3.0.0 ??