# how to get buffer percent of MobileVLCKit?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, vlc

like this question but in iOS. [Is there a way to get LibVlc loaded buffer percentage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42690992/is-there-a-way-to-get-libvlc-loaded-buffer-percentage)

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not implemented in VLCKit. It will appear in a future update, probably next year.

Answer (score 0):

try this lines of code and check your debug log its showing buffer percentage.

```
videoPlayer.libraryInstance.debugLogging = true
videoPlayer.libraryInstance.debugLoggingLevel = 3
```